# How do you type a circular reference in a namespace in a declaration file?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, .d.ts

I'm trying to type a UMD module (that I don't own so I can't change it) for the DefinitelyTyped project that has something like this (with actual functions of course):

```js
function getModule() {
    function fn1() {}
    function fn2() {}

    fn1.fn2 = fn2;
    return fn1.fn1 = fn1;
}

if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(getModule());
} else if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) { 
    module.exports = getModule();
} else {
    this.moduleName = getModule();
}
```

Using [the module-function.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html) template, I have this so far:

```
export as namespace moduleName;

export = fn1;

declare function fn1(): void;

declare namespace fn1 {
    function fn2(): void;
}
```

I then used [dts-gen](https://github.com/microsoft/dts-gen) to generate a .d.ts file for me to try to find out how to declare the `fn1` function again in the `fn1` namespace and got this:

```
/** Declaration file generated by dts-gen */

export = moduleName;

declare function moduleName(): void;

declare namespace moduleName {
    // Circular reference from moduleName
    const fn1: any;

    function fn2(): void;
}
```

However, when I tried combining the two in the following code I got the error `'fn1' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.`.

```
export as namespace moduleName;

export = fn1;

declare function fn1(): void;

declare namespace fn1 {
    function fn2(): void;
    const fn1: any;
}
```

I don't want to do the following because then it wouldn't represent the fact that you can do `require('moduleName').fn1.fn1.fn1.fn2` (or any number of `fn1`s.

```
export = moduleName;

declare function moduleName(): void;

declare namespace moduleName {
    function fn1(): void;
    function fn2(): void;
}
```

---

How would I type this module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an interface to accurately represent the recursive type:

```
export = fn1;

declare const fn1: Fn1

interface Fn1 {
  // The call signature of fn1
  (): void
  // The circular reference
  fn1: Fn1
  // Other functions
  fn2: () => void
}
```